# Wordpress remove EXIF Data from specific Thumb

Tags: php, images, thumbnails

Is it possible to **hook** in to action when uploading and resizing specific size added by `add_image_size( 'mini-placeholder', 32 )` for image in Wordpress, and remove EXIF Data, and set quality of this one to minimum (10/20%)?

I want to achieve small thumb under 1kb (the goal is smallest as it is possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using ImageMagick (the WP standard) as your library there is a filter called [`image_strip_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_strip_meta/) which controls whether the EXIF data must be preserved. Normally you would just use a boolean to do an overall setting, but you could easily make that a function like this:

```
add_filter ('image_strip_meta','wpse239481_conditional_strip')

function wpse239481_conditional_strip {
  if (...condition ..) return true else return false;
  }
```

The problem is in the condition. You would need to access the current thumbnail label, which doesn't trickle down from the [multi_resize method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_image_editor_imagick/multi_resize/) that sets thing going. However, the target width and height are known in the [resize function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_image_editor_imagick/thumbnail_image/) where the filter resides. Still, you can't access those dimensions inside the filter unless you hack the core to make this instance of `apply_filters` pass parameters.

Unless of course, someone smarter than me knows a trick.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Maybe I'll try to hook when attachment is uploaded,and create custom resize function.
I tried filter `add_filter ('add_attachment ','new_atachment' );`

But it wont work.